# Regex does not identify '#' for removing

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x, data-science

How to remove `'#'` from words in a string which are followed by `'#'` and not just `'#'` if it is present by itself, in the middle of the word or even at the end.

Currently I am using the regex expression:

```
test = "# #DataScience"
test = re.sub(r'\b#\w\w*\b', '', test)
```

for removing the "#' from the words starting with `'#'` but it does not work at all. It returns the string as it is

Can anyone please tell me why the `"#"` is not being recognized and removed?
Examples -

test - `"# #DataScience"`

Expected Output - `"# DataScience"`

Test - `"kjndjk#jnjkd"`

Expected Output - `"kjndjk#jnjkd"`

Test - `"# #DataScience #KJSBDKJ kjndjk#jnjkd #jkzcjkh# iusadhuish#""`

Expected Output -`"# DataScience KJSBDKJ  kjndjk#jnjkd jkzcjkh# iusadhuish#"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this :

```
test ="# #DataScience #KJSBDKJ kjndjk#jnjkd #jkzcjkh# iusadhuish#"
test = re.sub(r'(?<!\S)#(?=\S)', '', test)
```

Output :

```
# DataScience KJSBDKJ kjndjk#jnjkd jkzcjkh# iusadhuish#
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your pattern is that `#` is not a word character, therefore `\b` won't work with it.  You may instead use a lookbehind:

```
test = "#HereToHelp STUFF #DataScience"
print(test)
test = re.sub(r'(?:(?<= )|^)#\w+\b', '', test)
print(test)

#HereToHelp STUFF #DataScience
 STUFF
```

Comment: I just did that! Sorry for not accepting the answer before!

Comment: Actually, there is one more thing I am so sorry. This regex deletes the entire word starting from '#', I actually just wanted to delete the '#' and keep the remaining string. I just realized that my question was not correct. I am so sorry

Answer (score 0):

Your `\b` is not correctly placed.

Your regex expression should be:

```
r'#\b\w+\b'
```

And also, the `+` quantifier means 1 or more occurrences which saves the need for your `\w\w*`

Comment: Thank you so much for the help! The only case this regex didn't work for me was when the "#" was in the middle. As the expected output would have the entire word but the output was not. Eg - in "kjndjk#jnjkd", the output should be the word itself but it returned "kjndjk".

Comment: Is there always characters after the `#`?

Comment: Yes! The word will always sytart with a '#' and will be followed by words. The ouput should be the word but without the '#' in the start! I am soo sorry for the error in my question. Can you please help me out?

Comment: Ahhh, I gotcha.

Answer (score 0):

I know there's an accepted answer, but I came up with this regexp that seems to work fine too, personally I prefer this since it's easier to read for me:

```
(\A|[^#\d\w])#\w\w*\b
```

Comment: Hi! Thank you so much for your help! I actually made a mistake in my question. The resultant output should be the word without the "#" in the front. So for all words which start with a '#' and a re followed by some words, the output should be the word but wihtout the '#'. I am so sorry for the error in my question

Comment: It should be noted that you can change `\w\w*` to just `\w+` for the same effect

Comment: @Anay Purohit, you should update the question with a few examples of strings and expected results so it's easier to understand

Comment: @arieljuod I have just added examples based on your advice!

Comment: @Aggragoth I would really appreciate it if you could help me out!